# add column to df based on other column with lamdba function > column is made but values are 1: all the same and 2: memory numbers

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I found some answers but they didn't get me the right answer.

I have a df: lijst_df. Looks like this (355 rows in totall):

```
    gemeente        totaal 2016
0   AA EN HUNZE     64122320
1   AALSMEER        63209533
2   AALTEN          68151665
3   ACHTKARSPELEN   65699126
```

I want to add a new column. The value in the new column becomes the percentage of the sum in the allready existing column: totaal 2016.

I wrote this. Gives no Errors, makes the new column I want, but gives values as can be seen beneath the code:

```
for index, value in lijst_df.gemeente.items():
    lijst_df['% van totaal'] = lambda x: (df['totaal 2016']) /  (int((lijst_df['totaal 2016'].sum()))) * 100
```

Output:

```
     gemeente        totaal 2016   % van totaal

0   AA EN HUNZE       64122320  <function <lambda> at 0x000001D5A5C029D0>
1   AALSMEER          63209533  <function <lambda> at 0x000001D5A5C029D0>
2   AALTEN            68151665  <function <lambda> at 0x000001D5A5C029D0>
3   ACHTKARSPELEN     65699126  <function <lambda> at 0x000001D5A5C029D0>
```

Obviously something is wrong.... What do I miss? thanks again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like `sum` problem

```
# when you with pandas we should try not use for loop 
df['% van totaal'] = df['totaal 2016'] / df['totaal 2016'].sum()
```